# How can I resize panes in iTerm2 using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: iterm

How can I resize panes in iTerm2 using keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I had that hotkeys for different action so it didn't work

The hotkeys are for resizing the hight down/up are:

<kbd>control ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> / <kbd>↑</kbd>